# How do pass value in href parameters? If value is null i need to set that value is Zero?

Tags: php, null, href

I need to pass 3 parameters compulsory in hyper link like

```
<pre> <a href="<?= base_url('report/print/') . $loc . '/' . $dept . '/' . $e_name ?>" </pre>
```

if $loc or $dept or &e_name is none i need to be set that value is **zero**,otherwise i will get error,
for example  here i have passing 1 parameter value like $loc=1 and $dept= null &e_name=null  and got error like this..

http://localhost/final_approval/report/print/1//

will get this error
Message: Too few arguments to function Report::print(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\final_approval\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 533 and exactly 3 expected.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

http://localhost/final_approval/report/print/1//

instead of this i would like pass like this

http://localhost/final_approval/report/print/1/0/0

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: `. ($loc ?? 0) .`

Answer (score 0):

you can define your variables like this

```
$loc     = $loc?$loc:0;
$dept    = $dept?$dept:0;
$e_name  = $e_name?$e_name:0;
```

if your variables doesn't have an value then, it will be replaced by 0.

Comment: tried got same error..

Comment: $loc ? $loc: '0' Finally got it..